# .net make console exe hidden?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Windows Task Scheduler Wrapper to schedule the tasks (basically to launch an exe console every two minutes or so) in a .net desktop application.

However, I don't want it to pop-up the console every 5 minutes or even once.

How do I hide it?

I understand if I was using vb.net to launch the exe, there are several things I could have done. However, I am using windows task scheduler to launch it. What do you suggest in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The console app will only display if scheduled to run under your account. Simply create a new account, and schedule it to run under that account.

Comment: That's not an option. I will be distributing it to other people/friends. I can't ask everyone to create stuff for me

Comment: Does it need to be a console app?